# How does kernel know file is closed

Tags: filesystems, kernel, inotify, pyinotify

What exactly is the mechanism by which the linux knows that a file has been closed ?
I know commands such as INOTIFY would trigger IN_CLOSE_WRITE event when a file is closed. But how does it work ? What triggers close of a file ?

Similarly how does OS know that a file has been opened and where does it register that fact?

Answer (score 2):

The OS (i.e. kernel) is the one that actually opens and closes files. A program will have to tell the OS to open/close files on its behalf every time it wants to do so via *system calls*. The OS can simply keep track of these calls that go through itself.

Comment: Thanks. Let me ask my specific Q with an example: Say I start an FTP process on a Server A in the /tmp directory. I watch the directory using PYINOTIFY, the IN_CLOSE_WRITE event. When the FTP completes successfully, IN_CLOSE_WRITE gets triggered. But even if the FTP fails midstream for any reason, the IN_CLOSE_WRITE event gets triggered.  What is the mechanism by which the OS knows that the FTP process is no longer writing the file (as opposed to a ftp process with high latency that is still writing to the file but with very high latency)?

Comment: @A J: are you sure the FTP server is not manually closing the file after a burst of writes?

Comment: Where does the current Linux kernel store the which files are opened?

Comment: @moose Global open file table.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open file table that lists all the streams that are open and where they point to in memory.

This may help: http://www.cs.kent.edu/~walker/classes/os.f07/lectures/Walker-11.pdf